# Select data with count of data from another table

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by

I have two tables: `jobs' & 'clients'.

The `clients` table looks like this:

```
/----+------\
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  | Ben  |
| 2  | Max  |
\----+------/
```

And the `jobs` table:

```
/----+-----------+--------\
| id | client_id | status |
+----+-----------+--------+
| 1  |     1     |  alpha |
| 2  |     1     |  beta  |
| 3  |     1     |  beta  |
| 4  |     2     |  beta  |
\----+-----------+--------/
```

I'm looking to create a statement that will return the name of the client along with the number of times each status appears, like this:

```
/------+-------+------\
| name | alpha | beta |
+------+-------+------+
| Ben  |   1   |   2  |
| Max  |   0   |   1  |
\------+-------+------/
```

I do not require there to be a 0 where no values exist though.

I have tried `SELECT name, (SELECT status FROM jobs WHERE client_id = clients.id) FROM clients` but it returns more than one row in the sub-query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example with a solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80593/3

```
create table clients (id int, name varchar(10));
insert into clients values (1, 'Ben'), (2, 'Max');

create table jobs (id int, client_id int, status varchar(10));
insert into jobs values (1, 1, 'alpha'), (2, 1, 'beta'), (3, 1, 'beta'), (4, 2, 'beta');

select 
  clients.name, 
  sum(case when jobs.status = 'alpha' then 1 else 0 end) alpha,
  sum(case when jobs.status = 'beta' then 1 else 0 end) beta
from jobs
inner join clients 
  on jobs.client_id = clients.id
group by clients.name;
```

Comment: IMHO you can remove `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements from your answer. They are in your fiddle. but there is no need to put it as a part of answer.